# python patch on all tests with

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I want to set a single patch for all my tests, and I use `patch` for it.

ie:

```
 def setUp(self):
    self.patcher = patch('src.FetchFunction.caching.get_dynamo')
    self.addCleanup(self.patcher.stop)
    self.mock_foo = self.patcher.start()
```

now this `src.FetchFunction.caching.get_dynamo` is the path for my module I wanna patch.

But where I use this module in the past and I wanted to patch in my tests I did:

```
patch('path.to.tested.module.get_dynamo')
```

now if I do the first example my `get_dynamo` is not patched

BUT if I copy the same path as the same example, the `get_dynamo` is patched.

BUT that means I need to patch it for each single use of `get_dynamo` in my code.

I mean if I use it from `file1` so

```
patch('path.to.file1.get_dynamo')
```

and if I wanna patch at `file2` so

```
patch('path.to.file2.get_dynamo')
```

any ideas how to set it up properly?

Thanks

Comment: I believe this question has been asked and answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821465/how-to-properly-use-mock-in-python-with-unittest-setup

Use patch as a decorator on class level.

Comment: Thanks @ThePjot already saw that, but I'm asking if this mocked file is getting called from several files so the patch path is different