# How to mock vault hvac.Client() method

Tags: python, unit-testing

Here I am using unittest framework and Python.

```
def getsomevalue(name):
    client = hvac.Client(url ="http://1.2.3.4:31485",token = "abcdefghijkkk")                               
    sampledata= client.read('secret/data/somedata')
    return sampledata
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly use mock in python with unittest setUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821465/how-to-properly-use-mock-in-python-with-unittest-setup)

Answer (score 1):

So pretty much what I did was create a mock hvac client class and then patch to replace the vault client instance in your code.

in other words it is something like this:

```
def mock_vault_read(*args, **kwargs):
   class MockVault:
       def read(self, **kwargs):
          return {some_data}
```

and then for your test you can write:

```
@patch("hvac.Client", side_effect=mock_vault_read):
def test_read(self, mock_vault):
   name = "test"
   result = getsomevalue(name)
   self.assertEquals(result, {some_data})
```

What this is doing is creating a magic mock mock_vault and replacing all instances of hvac.Client that it can find with that magic mock. The mock_vault_read is a side_effect of that magic mock, essentially saying that when you call the magic mock, call the mock_vault_read function. This can be further customized for any function need for hvac.