# Pytest: Setting up mocks with functions without side effects

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have a question related the answer of this question:

[pytest: setup a mock for every test function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924026/pytest-setup-a-mock-for-every-test-function)

I like the idea of using functions that receive the mock objects via arguments. In this way, the setting up of mocks can be reused. I conclude from the answer that mock objects are mutable in Python and changing them inside the function will have the side effect that they are changed outside. However, I consider it as dangerous to have side effects. So, I suggest the followoing:

```
def test(self, mock1):
    mock1 = setup_mock1_to_always_xxx(mock1)
    ...
```

with

```
def setup_mock1_to_always_xxx(mock1):
    # create a copy to avoid side effects
    mock1 = mock1.copy() # how to copy a Mock?
    mock1.return_value = "my return value"
    return mock1
```

Would this be possible?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just setup another mock rather then copying? `mock1` in your example can be a fixture with a function scope that will be called before the execution of each test, so each test gets a fresh mock supplied.

Comment: @hoefling, I think this is the most elegant answer. Would you like to make an answer out of your comment, maybe with giving an example fixture? I don't want to take your credits, otherwise I will do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest injecting mocks using [`pytest` fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) instead of manual mock copying. The function-scoped fixtures (the default ones) reevaluate for each test. Example: assume you have a module

```
# mod.py

def spam():
    return eggs()


def eggs():
    return "eggs"
```

and a test

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from mod import spam


@patch("mod.eggs")
def test_bacon(mock1):
    mock1.return_value = "bacon"
    assert spam() == "bacon"
```

and now you want to refactor it into testing against `bacon` and `bacon with eggs`. Move out the patching inside a fixture:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch
from mod import spam


@pytest.fixture
def eggs_mock():
    with patch("mod.eggs") as mock1:
        yield mock1


def test_bacon(eggs_mock):
    eggs_mock.return_value = "bacon"
    assert spam() == "bacon"


def test_bacon_with_eggs(eggs_mock):
    eggs_mock.return_value = "bacon with eggs"
    assert spam() == "bacon with eggs"
```

You now have two different mocks of the `mod.eggs` function, one unique mock in each test.

#### `unittest`-style tests

This approach also works with `unittest` test classes, although the injection is a bit more verbose since `unittest.TestCase`s don't accept arguments in test methods. This is the same approach as described in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50135020/2650249). In the example below, I store the `eggs_mock` fixture return value in a `Tests` instance attribute via using an additional [autouse fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#autouse-fixtures-xunit-setup-on-steroids):

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
from mod import spam


@pytest.fixture
def eggs_mock():
    with patch("mod.eggs") as mock1:
        yield mock1


class Tests(TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def inject_eggs_mock(self, eggs_mock):
        self._eggs_mock = eggs_mock

    def test_bacon(self):
        self._eggs_mock.return_value = "bacon"
        assert spam() == "bacon"


    def test_bacon_with_eggs(self):
        self._eggs_mock.return_value = "bacon with eggs"
        assert spam() == "bacon with eggs"
```